# Java - Error running public classes through the console

Tags: java, class, public

I am following this book Head First Java. I've typed in the code for this guess number program. I've had great succession so far with all the code in the book. But when I run this code I get the following errors:

```
javac GameLauncher.java:1:error class GuessGame is public, should be declared in a file named GuessGame.java
```

The file I saved is the one with the main inside `GameLauncher.java`.

This repeats for another public class called Player. I have looked around on the net and saw people saying that I have to save the class file which has the main inside. Which I have done. It works fine when I remove the 'public' but this shouldn't be the case. I have also saved files under `Player.java` and `GuessGame.java` but still get errors.

Very new to this all and haven't run into much trouble until now. I know it's going to be something simple.

Comment: Can you share some code please?

Comment: You need one file per public class

Comment: You seem not tried to google the error. Who do you think the QA sites and internet archive exist for, for people like you who ignore them?

Comment: You should create `GuessGame` in a different file and `GameLauncher` in separate file as both are `public`.

Comment: I didn't share any code because there is no error or any problem in the code itself. Just the 'public' for the classes. I did have a look around the net. I don't have hours upon hours to search the net.

Answer (score 0):

Java source files may contain zero or one `public` classes, if you have more than one in a single `.java` file, you will get this error.

Basically, you always should have only one top-level class in every Java source file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `public class GuessGame` into a file named `GuessGame.java` and `public class Player` into a file named `Player.java`

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I did create multiple files e.g Player.java and GuessGame.java. I will just use one public class for now in the main.

Answer (score 0):

A java file must contain at most 1 `public` class, and the name of the file should be exactly the same as the classname plus the extension ".java".

If you want muliple `public` classes, use multiple files. If you want multiple classes in 1 file, use the package access modifier for all the other classes.

i.e. class `GuessGame` must be placed in `GuessGame.java` or the `public` access modifier before it must be removed.